# How to check Google Analytics Testing behind .htaccess wall?

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

I am implementing Google Analytics Test and I need to check if it works before we deploy it to live. But our staging server is behind a .htaccess security. So the Google check from Analytics does not work.

Is there another way to check it? What is the parameter that is send when a test case is send with pageview call?

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with checking your pageview request. When you see such data in your request to Google Analytics, then you know it works.

Parameters:

```
xid:    b6dd_g1VSjKKbcyYsNXw2A //test ID
xvar:   0 // test variant
```

**But:** this does not say that your Goal is working. It just says that your implementation of your check is correct and will be send to Google Analytics.